# Mockito SpyBean throws an UnfinishedStubbingException

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I'm trying to partially mock a service using Mockito's Spy, overriding a method to make it return consistent data for testing, but said spy throws an UnfinishedStubbingException for no apparent reason.

This is my test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ApplicationIT {

    private CompletableFuture<JobList> jobList;

    @SpyBean
    private Service serviceSpy;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        initMocks(this);

        jobList = new CompletableFuture<>();
        jobList.complete(jobList.newBuilder()
                .addAllJobs(jobTestData.getTestJob().getJobs()).build()); 

        Mockito.doReturn(jobList).when(serviceSpy).fetchJob();  
        Mockito.doNothing().when(serviceSpy).reportSuccess(Mockito.any());
    }

    @Test
    public void fetchJobCallTest() {
        Mockito.verify(serviceSpy, timeout(60000).atLeastOnce()).fetchJob();
    }

    @Test
    public void reportSuccessCallTest() {       
        Mockito.verify(serviceSpy, timeout(60000).atLeastOnce()).reportSuccess(Mockito.any());
    }
}
```

Both tests fail with a `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException` pointing to `Mockito.doReturn(jobList).when(serviceSpy).fetchJob();` at  `Mockito.doNothing().when(serviceSpy).reportSuccess(Mockito.any());`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like spying async methods breaks Mockito. I removed the async from the method as an experiment and immediately Mockito no longer threw those exceptions.

Answer (score -3):

```
UnfinishedStubbingException means you are not mocking properly
this is not the right way of mocking a method... Mockito.doReturn(jobList).when(serviceSpy).fetchJob();
You can try below...
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
```

Comment: I fall in the third case: ```doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();``` -> ```doReturn(jobList).when(serviceSpy).fetchJob();```

Comment: fetchJob() is private method or public method?... tell me so that I can tell u exact what u want

Comment: ```fetchJob()``` is a ```@Async public CompletableFuture<JobList>``` method